# How to supply multiple ImagePullSecrets to an s2i build in OpenShift

Tags: docker, build, openshift, buildconfig, s2i

I'm trying to build an OCI image using the s2i mechanism of OpenShift.
The Dockerfile is multi-stage, both base images are hosted inside two different, only privately accessible docker repositories.

My BuildConfig looks like this:

```
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  name: ${NAME}
spec:
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  nodeSelector: { }
  output:
    pushSecret:
      name: ${PUSH_SECRET}
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: >-
        ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}
  postCommit: { }
  resources: { }
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    binary: { }
    type: Binary
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      pullSecret:
        name: ${PULL_SECRET}
    type: Docker
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  triggers: [ ]
```

I know I can supply the ImagePullSecret to use with the `.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.pullSecret.name` field. But how can I use multiple pull secrets, i.e. enable the build to pull from two separate private docker registries?

Creating the ImagePullSecrets in OpenShift and then assigning them to the `builder` ServiceAccount did not work, as s2i seems to ignore this configuration and only use the secrets listed in the BuildConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field : `spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.pullSecret` must contains only one `pullSecret`.

> pullSecret: [LocalObjectReference](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/rest_api/objects/index.html#io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference): The name of a Secret that would be used for setting up the authentication for pulling the container images from the private Docker registries.

Make sure you have define all registry server name/auth inside your pull secret, for example:

```
// dockerconfig.json
{
 "auths":{
  "registry.yourdomain.com":{"auth":"<hash>","email":"<email_address>"},
  "cloud.openshift.com":{"auth":"<hash>","email":"<email_address>"},
  "quay.io/repository-main":{"auth":"<hash>","email":"<email_address>"} 
 }
}

// Create pull secret from dockerconfig file
$ oc create secret generic <pull_secret_name> \
  --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/dockerconfig.json> \
  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

// Add the secret to your service account
$ oc secrets link builder <pull_secret_name> --for=pull
```

> When configuring the BuildConfig, the PullSecret can be overridden to manually choose the ImagePullSecret used by the OpenShift Build when there are multiple to choose from in the `Builder` ServiceAccount.

Comment: Thanks, although I already knew (see my answer :))

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple auths inside a single pull secret.